# Stacked bar plotting dataframe groups

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot stacked bar chart from a dataframe for several hours. I'm sorry if this is a bare question, but I just can't make it work, I need help.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
                                 _id        date                              news_source
0   2715eeada6726024df20e6938ef09f64  2019-12-23                    airport-suppliers.com
1   d068a3d0b24d2a348ff8c8a856aba86c  2019-12-23                    airport-suppliers.com
17  552d7bb9f7d3fd689dd308dc7650baac  2019-12-23                    airport-suppliers.com
20  82be33a041204fd008ba5093607310f6  2019-12-23                    airport-suppliers.com
21  4044907f5b6d5610ec59a03c75e0554c  2019-12-23  airportsinternational.keypublishing.com
22  db4e1e4d1246abc3304e5d77688424dc  2019-12-23  airportsinternational.keypublishing.com
23  b7f57b63218190d249d19624bbdcb520  2019-12-23           internationalairportreview.com
27  84d5377bd8755a685100e408140c4ab1  2019-12-23           internationalairportreview.com
28  8289a1c1b3fa3f618c332d61023eae00  2019-12-16               passengerterminaltoday.com
29  f4f020f09ee5f95499a26c43cfd82d2d  2019-12-16  airportsinternational.keypublishing.com
..                               ...         ...                                      ...
59  a18388a1c77889bdbe6aaa9238a8d21a  2019-12-16                    airport-suppliers.com
62  5cd894a9fa587ab4267adfd23f01e1c4  2019-12-16  airportsinternational.keypublishing.com
66  bb7d05d61f999b1f0b317d21c6c23c0c  2019-12-16  airportsinternational.keypublishing.com
70  f49b9ce330198aec666cb90275d293b2  2019-12-16           internationalairportreview.com
71  af893db09fad9335413ce5c325ced712  2019-12-16               passengerterminaltoday.com
72  e21dc60cfda457b03a6dba6ab44aa3b1  2019-12-16               passengerterminaltoday.com
81  963760af4b4653d175902f4d6285ff0a  2019-12-16               passengerterminaltoday.com
82  778b572be28fd25f394cfa41bbc5aa4a  2019-12-16                    airport-suppliers.com
```

The final plot I want to show is like [this](https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68573aed-e59f-418e-98f7-36f2ae503a1f/5-stacked-bar-chart-large-opt.png), but instead of strategies there will be weekly dates, `news_source` instead of Products, and counts is the same.

What I tried is groupby by `date` and `news_source`, then counting them. Then the rest of my work just got messed up and in the end I couldn't make it to get in a format like the example in [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py). Also, the amount of unique news_source, date may change over time, so I'm avoiding hardcoding things as much as I can.

**The grouping:**

```py
groups = df.groupby(['date', 'news_source'])["_id"].count()
```

If you need them as dictionary:

```py
counts = defaultdict(dict)
for index, count in zip(groups.index, groups):
    try:
        counts[index[0]][index[1]] += count
    except KeyError:
        counts[index[0]][index[1]] = count
```

Output is:

```
{'2019-12-16': {'airport-suppliers.com': 9,
                'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com': 12,
                'internationalairportreview.com': 19,
                'passengerterminaltoday.com': 21},
 '2019-12-23': {'airport-suppliers.com': 21,
                'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com': 2,
                'internationalairportreview.com': 5}}
```

If you know how to do it properly, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

**Here is the code to generate minimal reproducible example:**

```py
import pandas as pd

dates = ['2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16']

sources = ['airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'airportsinternational.keypublishing.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'passengerterminaltoday.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'airport-suppliers.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com', 'internationalairportreview.com']

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": dates, "news_source": sources})
```

Comment: Your reproducible example doesn't include an `_id` column.

Comment: It's not really necessary in this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  I added counts for your data:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['date', 'news_source']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

Then, I used [pd.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), set the following index, columns, and values parameters.  Then include an aggfunc, which is sum() in this case.

```
pd.crosstab(index=df1['date'], columns=df1['news_source'], values=df1['count'], aggfunc=sum).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it and give feedback asap.

Comment: @emremrah No prob! I don't plot a lot of stuff, but though this would be interesting to try out.  I think the output is `ax`, so you could integrate it into a matplotlib thing if you wanted.